# Form gives error when trying to append after question mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send visitors to http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=http://google.com?c

Gives the error

> The comments plugin requires an href parameter.

This part is rendered correctly: http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php

but the stuff after the question mark fails to be included

```
<script>
function go(){
    var uri = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php' 
        + encodeURI('?href=http://google.com?c');

    window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML = 
        '<form target="_parent" method="get" action="' 
        + uri 
        + '"></form>';
    window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit();
}    
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"> </iframe>?
```

Comment: Try `var uri = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?' 
        + encodeURIComponent('href=http://google.com?c');`

Comment: What Musa said, this is because URI component encoded version of `?` is `%3F`

Comment: This [page](http://silkenhut.com/the-comments-plugin-requires-an-href-parameter-solution/) leads me to believe that if you're not having luck with `encodeURIComponent`, it may be conflicting plugin code.

Comment: if you wrap the url in a url shortener it works. it has to do with stuff after the question mark not being appended

Comment: Okay try this `var uri = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=' + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com?c');`

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
var uri = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?' 
    + encodeURIComponent('href=http://google.com?c');
```

If you encode the first `?` it no longer serves to separate the URL from its parameters.

Comment: `encodeURI('?') === '?'`, `encodeURIComponent('?') === '%3F'`. I think you mean the latter.

Comment: does not work. i tried virtually all the combinations before posting this question.

Comment: @SeanKinsey It shouldn't matter, it will be decoded automatically.

Comment: @Barmar What gave you that impression? Because it's not true. Try https://www.google.com/?q%3Dfoo and https://www.google.com/?q=foo

Comment: @SeanKinsey My mistake, I thought %-decoding occurred before parsing the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Only the keys and value of the query should be encoded, not the ?,& or = as these are the characters that structure the query.

```
var uri = 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?href=' 
    + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com?c');
```